# Unable to determine the desired template from the input template name: blazorserverside

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to setup blazor server side but I keep getting this problem when trying to install it

following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio-code) from microsoft and I get this error in powershell window

```
PS D:\blazorTesting> dotnet new blazorserverside -o WebApplicationServerSide
Usage: new [options]

Options:
  -h, --help          Displays help for this command.
  -l, --list          Lists templates containing the specified name. If no name is specified, lists all templates.
  -n, --name          The name for the output being created. If no name is specified, the name of the current directory is used.
  -o, --output        Location to place the generated output.
  -i, --install       Installs a source or a template pack.
  -u, --uninstall     Uninstalls a source or a template pack.
  --nuget-source      Specifies a NuGet source to use during install.
  --type              Filters templates based on available types. Predefined values are "project", "item" or "other".
  --dry-run           Displays a summary of what would happen if the given command line were run if it would result in a template creation.
  --force             Forces content to be generated even if it would change existing files.
  -lang, --language   Filters templates based on language and specifies the language of the template to create.


Unable to determine the desired template from the input template name: blazorserverside.
The following templates partially match the input. Be more specific with the template name and/or language.

Templates                                 Short Name            Language      Tags
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Blazor (server-side)                      blazorserverside      [C#]          Web/Blazor
Blazor (Server-side in ASP.NET Core)      blazorserverside      [C#]          Web/Blazor/ServerSide

Examples:
    dotnet new blazorserverside
    dotnet new blazorserverside --auth Individual
    dotnet new --help
```

Comment: What is the output of `dotnet --version`?

Comment: @John  3.0.100-preview6-012264

Comment: Have you performed Step 2?: `dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.0.0-preview6.19307.2`

Comment: If you have and it isn't working, restart your machine.

Comment: Yes I have performed step 2, and I did a restart although I am sure it has nothing to do with the issue at all. Still the same error appears

Comment: Do a dotnet new --list see if you can see the Blazor templates if not do step 2 again. Show us any errors.  I ran your command and it works fine

Comment: Did you remember to install the preview SDK?

Comment: @PeterMorris i think they answered that in the second comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Introduction

Dotnet preview6 sdk comes with Blazor server side templates. You need to install templates only if you want to create hosted, client side or libraries.

To install templates you should to use `dotnet new -i` with the name of template and, optionally, the **version**.

### Issue

When you added the templates you forgot to set the version of templates, you did:

```
dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates  # Bad. Don't copy-paste
```

Instead of:

```
dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.0.0-preview6.19307.2
```

For this reason, do you have the `blazorserverside` for twice: one for each version.

### Solution

Good news, it is easy to fix.

**Step 1**: remove wrong templates:

```
dotnet new -u Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates
```

**Step 2**: install [optionally] new ones. Remember you don't need this templates to create just a server side blazor app.

```
dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.0.0-preview6.19307.2
```

Enjoy with your labs.