# Duplicate Project Template + Missing Self-hosted Template

Tags: blazor

Is anyone experiencing a strange duplicate project template issue as described here (link: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/12388?

So now I'm presently unable to create Self-hosted Blazor Project using the project templates...

Just wondering if it's just a problem with my environment or more wide spread

Comment: This helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56881473/unable-to-determine-the-desired-template-from-the-input-template-name-blazorser/56882762#56882762

Comment: perfect thanks @daniherrera

Comment: Hi John, The issue was with template versions as I linked to you?

Comment: Yes, it now just a `labelling`(still shows duplicate templates items) issue but at least I can work with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is anyone experiencing ...

Yes. The extension was updated I think. It's set to auto-update and there are no release notes or anything so I'm not 100% sure.

> So now I'm presently unable to create Self-hosted Blazor Project

No, one of those duplicates is the self-hosted triplet. On my PC it's the top one, but maybe try it out in a temp folder first